# How do I release one audio track and not all audio ionic/cordova cordova-plugin-media

Tags: ios, cordova, audio

I'm using cordova/ionic and cordova-plugin-media to crossfade two music tracks together.

I've got a problem where I'm crossfading one Media object with another.

It works fine but when I call .release() on the finished Media object in Android, but on ios, .release() kills all audio. If I don't call release in ios I end up with a 'memory leak'. I say 'memory leak' because it isn't really - I know that that object is still there.

It doesn't matter if I reset the object and null it, according to xcode, the memory footprint steadily gets larger.

my cut down loadTrack code:

```
    var loadTrack = function(playerName,track){

        var pn = playerName;

        var mediaOnEnd = function(){
            console.log('mediaOnEnd RELEASING: '+pn);
            $scope.player.media[pn].release();
        };

        var mediaError = function(error){
            prepareNextTrack(pn);
        };

        var mediaStatus = function(status){
            switch(status){
                case 2:
                    console.log('playing:'+pn);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    console.log('stop:'+pn);
                    break;
            }
        };

        $scope.player.media[pn] = new $window.Media(
            config.local_path+$scope.currentTrack.id+config.file_extention,
            mediaOnEnd,
            mediaError,
            mediaStatus
        );

        $scope.player.media[pn].play();

    };
```

When mediaOnEnd is called, or when I call it in my crossfade function (not included), all audio is stopped.

Is there anywhere I can do this properly?